# Which versions of tls are supported by ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-10.04, curl, tls

I have a server running an old version of ubuntu and I need to be able to use tls 1.1/1.2 via curl. It doesn't seem to be currently supported (my version of curl is 7.19.7). Is it possible to get this running under ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Build from source – https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html? But to be honest, sticking with a server that has been EOL'd more than two years ago is not a good idea.

Comment: I tried building from source, but I'm getting an error 'Unsupported SSL protocol version'. I think it relates to the version of openssl. I didn't even realise that version of ubuntu had been EOL'd; I'm not really a sysadmin, and everything has been running fine. Yes, certainly the best option is to upgrade the OS, but I'm looking for contingencies since that's quite a major task.

Comment: I guess then the dependencies are also quite outdated, e.g. `libssl`, as you're observing. “Everything has been running fine” is of course the problem – OS upgrades may of course break stuff, but especially w.r.t. critical security vulnerabilities, if this is a public facing server (even if it isn't!), I'd try to plan an upgrade to the latest LTS, which should give you support until 2021, if I'm not mistaken.